# Need To delete cell from UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I can't get out of this, I have a UICollectionView with custom cell and every cell has a X button to delete it from the list, I pass to the button.tag the IndexPath.item and on the delete function i've implemented the following method:

```
- (void)DeleteProductFromArray:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"item: %d",button.tag);
    TagHelpConverted = [NSNumber numberWithInt:button.tag];
    TagHelp = button.tag;
    if(DeletedCells.count == 0)
    {
        [DeletedCells addObject:TagHelpConverted];
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < DeletedCells.count; i++)
        {
            if([TagHelpConverted compare:DeletedCells[i]] == NSOrderedDescending)
            {
                TagHelp--;
                NSLog(@"ho diminuito il tag di 1");
            }
        }
        [DeletedCells addObject:TagHelpConverted];
    }

    NSLog(@"valore tagHelp:%d", TagHelp);
    [_feedItems removeObjectAtIndex:TagHelp];

    [self.customCollectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:TagHelp inSection:0]]];
    [self.customCollectionView reloadData];

}
```

The problem is that when scrolling the UICollectionView calls the `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {` and my NSMutableArray that stores which button has already been clicked has "old values" that compared to the new ones assigned by this method  makes the app delete random items inside the UICollectionView.
I searched on the Internet for help about deleting UICollectionView cells but I found almost anything, I'm struggling very hard on this one but I can't find a way to get out, please if anyone has a solution help me

Comment: A side tip: variable should start with small case. eg `tagHelpConverted`, `tagHelp`, `deletedCells`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete cells from a collectionView you can remove them from the data source and reload the collectionView. You want to make sure you keep your data source in sync with what is on the screen. Basically, keep your data source how you want it and call [collectionView reloadData].

```
- (void)didTapDeleteCellBtn:(UIButton *)deleteCellBtn {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)deleteCellBtn.superview.superview; // Make sure this gets the right cell for the button
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.customCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
    id item = self.feedItems[indexPath.row];
    NSMutableArray *updatedFeedItems = [self.feedItems mutableCopy];
    [updatedFeedItems removeObject:item];
    self.feedItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:updatedFeedItems];
    [self.customCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I edited the code a little and now it works perfectly, THANK YOU!

Comment: this stuff should best be nested inside the block in performBatchUpdates:completion on the UICollectionView